# Any differences between 領収書 and 受領書?

Tags: nuances, definitions

First time asking a question here. I was curious if there is any relevant distinction between these two words that mean receipt: 領収書 and 受領書.

Comment: BTW: the difference between 領収書 and レシート might actually make for a slightly more [interesting](https://invoice.moneyforward.com/receipts-lp/basic/receipts-difference) Q&A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

受領書 is letter of acceptance of **any items**. 領収書 only of **money**.

I suppose most times when you issue what is named "receipt" is about money. In these cases, Japanese conventionally prefers the narrower term, 領収書.